# Automatic Date Default

Tags: list, column, date

I have a list with a date column, which is updated every month for the 8th business day of the month. I would like that column to change automatically every month to December 8, January 8, etc. without needing to manually fill this out. Can this be done and, if so, how?  This is time sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few ways to do it.

- create a workflow using Visual Studios to set the date based on c# code. (probably the MS approved way)
- powershell script that can be triggered from windows task scheduler to populate that field after the content's been created (if content needs the date during time of creation, this won't help)
- inject jquery into the template/page to prepopulate the field (not ideal but possible)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirements but a calculated column may be what you need if you just need the list to give the next month's date if you require an OOTB solution.

```
=IF(DAY(TODAY())<8,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),8),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,8))
```

Another option would be to combine a workflow that calculates and saves the next month's date with an information management retention policy that triggers that workflow when the date is reached and repeats every month.

Comment: Thanks! Where and How would I add that within the column settings?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing a simple C# console application that will leverage the [SPLIST class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.aspx).

You can choose to follow the Powershell method or the C# method, either way both are good options. I would then leverage the Task Scheduler to schedule the script/application to run at your desired frequency.

Hope this helps.